# Certificate Transparency check failing in Charles Proxy

Tags: ios, security, ssl, ssl-certificate, charles-proxy

I tried sniffing packets on my iOS app using Charles proxy. I added the Charles Proxy certificate on my iPhone trusted certificate store. I have the certificate transparency flag for my app turned on, which is provided by the iOS platform. I was able to sniff the packets successfully.

As per my understanding, on the client-side, if the Certificate Transparency check is on, it checks for the validity of the SCT. Why I was able to sniff the packets successfully? Why didn't the SSL connection terminated as the certificate transparency check was on?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to see the encrypted traffic also ?

Event in SSL pinning solution traffic can be intercepted but it's all encrypted.